# Add get request before Instapy session execution

Tags: python, instapy

Note -> I'm javascript developer, don't had experience with Python

In quickstart.py script, I added request to pull profile from some API

```
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:3333/api/v1/internal/profiles/1")
profile = response.text

print(profile)
set_workspace(path="fullpath" + insta_username)
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,password=insta_password,headless_browser=True)

with smart_run(session):
     session.follow_user_followers(['xxxx'], amount=10, randomize=False)
```

I expected to first execute request, then run Instapy session

Currently behavior is that first run Instapy script, with INFO console infos, follows profile followers and after that prints response from API request and after that sets workspace